# Color change on hover transition doesn't work (CSS)

Tags: html, css, colors, hover, css-transitions

I am trying to have simple header buttons that change color when they are hovered over.  I may have accidentally over complicated my CSS, because I was originally doing something different.  Regardless, even with a !important, the color transition doesn't work.  Note:  All of the stuff about line-height and header.smaller is still being used for a shrinking header, which I did not include in the code (so please don't delete them). Thanks! See code below (also on https://jsfiddle.net/j9f14cyw/2/):

CSS:

```
header {
  top: 0;
  width: calc(90% - 80px);
  padding: 0 40px;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff0000;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

header nav * {
  -o-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
}

header.smaller {
  height: 75px;
}

#banner {
  width: calc(80% - 40px);
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 68px;
  background-image: url(../img/favicon.png);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a.hdrBtn {
  font-family: 'futuraBook', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  -o-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -o-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  line-height: 80px;
}

a.hdrBtn:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}

a.hdrBtn:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "|";
  color: lightgrey;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.hdrLogo {
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-family: 'futuraLight', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
}

header.smaller nav *,
header.smaller a {
  -o-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  line-height: 35px;
}

header.smaller nav {
  float: right;
}

#navImg {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 0 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <header>

    <nav>
      <a class="hdrBtn" href="">Stuff1</a>
      <a class="hdrBtn" href="">Stuff2</a>
      <a class="hdrBtn" href="">Stuff3</a>
      <a class="hdrBtn" href="">Stuff4</a>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be working here: https://jsfiddle.net/674svcpa/
Isnt the color change to red on hover what u wanted to do?

Answer (score 2):

The color change in your jsfiddle is working. If it does not work on your system however, I would try to set the hover css to important and check if the results are as expected then:

```
a.hdrBtn:hover {
  color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

I would also inspect the element in the console (e.g Chrome) to check if there are other classes or styles overwriting your changes

Also, maybe you are trying to do achieve something different than you explained here. But a color change of the  tag effects in your case only the font (not like a box round it or so, as you haven't created one)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I made a mistake in my post.  What's not working is the .15 second color transition.

Answer (score 0):

in this class (a.hdrBtn) you don't need to add this transition :

```
-o-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete header nav * in CSS code and change to **header nav :hover**

Full code:

Edit CSS & HTML:

```css
header {
  top: 0;
  width: calc(90% - 80px);
  padding: 0 40px;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff0000;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

header nav :hover {
  -o-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
}

header.smaller {
  height: 75px;
}

#banner {
  width: calc(80% - 40px);
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 68px;
  background-image: url(../img/favicon.png);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a.hdrBtn {
  font-family: 'futuraBook', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  -o-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -o-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  line-height: 80px;
}

a.hdrBtn:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}

a.hdrBtn:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "|";
  color: lightgrey;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.hdrLogo {
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-family: 'futuraLight', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
  transition: line-height 0.2s linear !important;
}

header.smaller nav *,
header.smaller a {
  -o-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -moz-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  -ms-transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  transition: color 0.15s linear !important;
  line-height: 35px;
}

header.smaller nav {
  float: right;
}

#navImg {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 0 30px;
}
nav #color1:hover{
  color:blue;
}
nav  #color2:hover{
  color:red;
}
nav #color3:hover{
  color:green;
}
nav  #color4:hover{
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>

    <nav>
      <a id="color1" class="hdrBtn" href="">Stuff1</a>
      <a id="color2" class="hdrBtn" href="">Stuff2</a>
      <a id="color3" class="hdrBtn" href="">Stuff3</a>
      <a id="color4" class="hdrBtn" href="">Stuff4</a>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: your code does the same thing as his code already. if you add a hover event to the entire nav bar, you will not be able to create a color change on different buttons. all you would do is change the color of the entire nav bar on hover

Comment: @tom . I've been editing the HTML and CSS code in Snippet .. or you can see through JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/j9f14cyw/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/j9f14cyw/3/)